# How to add dynamic PDO mapping in EL6751?

Tags: can-bus, plc, twincat, canopen

I have CANOpen slave device, which requires dynamic PDO mapping. Currently device has an EDS file, but loading it in TwinCAT produces CANOpen errors since PDO's are not configured properly in EDS and should be configured dynamically. What's the procedure of dynamic PDO configuration in TwinCAT3 for EL6751 CANOpen master terminal?

[image]

Comment: Finding any PLC programmers here is probably hard, I'd try asking this on https://electronics.stackexchange.com instead where the chances of finding one are slightly better.

Comment: That being said, my experience over the years from trying to support various poor souls trying to integrate CANopen products in a PLC, is that it is always cumbersome. I would strongly recommend to reach out to the PLC support, whenever doing things a bit out of the ordinary such as dynamic mapping. You _should_ be able to do this in run-time by accessing your own OD and writing to the PDO mapping indices, but I wouldn't know how to do that in your PLC.